# Asp .net core how to load html file byte[] to iframe src view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

I'm going to load .html file (byte[]) from my database to < iframe src="" id='chgit'> html element.

```
public byte[] file { get; set; }
```

I did try this but fail:

```
public FileResult QuestionHTML(byte[] requestFile)
        {
            byte[] file = requestFile;
            return File(file, "application/html");
        }
```

then in view cshtml :

```
$("#chgit").attr('src', '@Url.Action("QuestionHTML", Model.Questions[0].file)');
```

result :

```
Request URL Too Long

HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.
```

Please need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured it out by now but the form needs to use the `POST` method. Also the encoding (`enctype`) should be `multipart/form-data`.

If you use the `GET` method then the content of the file will be put in the request URL which, as the error indicates, will make it too long.